# In Sign-up page even blank spaces are getting registered , mysql database -php- android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have got a sign-up activity in which there are 5 entries, I want them all to be NOT `null`, everything is working fine but it is also taking `null` values and it is getting into MySQL database (if I used the below code to solve this problem then the button (SIGN-UP button show in the image below) does not do anything).

```
 public void func_signup_reg(View view){
    str_name = name.getText().toString();
    str_ign = ign.getText().toString();
    str_email = email.getText().toString();
    str_user = reg_username.getText().toString();
    str_pass = reg_password.getText().toString();
    Finduser finduser = new Finduser(this);
    String type = "signup";
    if(!((str_name != null && !str_name.isEmpty()) ||( str_ign != null && str_ign.isEmpty() )||( str_email != null && str_email.isEmpty() )||( str_user != null && str_user.isEmpty() )||( str_pass != null && str_pass.isEmpty() )))
    {finduser.execute(type, str_name, str_ign, str_email, str_user, str_pass);}

}

}
```

[image: Sign Up Form]
[image: Database Layout]
[image: PhpCode]

Comment: There is not enough here for us to go on. Show us your PHP

Comment: Is it really adding NULL or is it allowing empty values? Adding the PHP code would be useful, or changing the tags to reflect what is being used.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  please check it out

Comment: @HemantVyas could you please add the code as code and not as image? It would make everything much much easier.

Comment: @ManuToMatic yeah sorry for that but i tried to add code but it was getting messy (new to stackoverflow).

Comment: @HemantVyas you can paste it and use the "Code"-tag to format it. :)

Comment: @chris85 it was allowing empty values , but after putting these restriction
" if(!((str_name != null && !str_name.isEmpty())" it is not taking any value , button does not do anything.

Comment: So you probably have a JAVA error, update the tags, I'm not sure what your code is doing but it is JAVA, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem!! , used the if condition in the Finduser( this class extends Asynctask) class side and it is working now.